# Does a website service for image editing need to be ADA compliant for visually impaired users?

Tags: internet, software, constitutional-law, eula, americans-with-disabilities-act

I'm getting ready to launch my website for an image editing service. I had come across quite a few articles on how they need to be ADA compliant to offer service in the US without legal troubles. However, due to the nature of the services I'm trying to offer, there would be no practical way of making the image editor accesible to visually impaired or blind users. Can a disclaimer or EULA notice popup I add to confirm the user is not of visual impairment upon entry to the website be enough of a guard to prevent legal action on the basis that the site is not ADA complaint for visual impairment? Thanks a ton for any suggestions/help.

Comment: ADA requires *reasonable* accomodations, so if there are non possible you have nothing to do. Note however that a blind user might still want to use your website to, for example, convert an image format or something like that, this is certainly dooable using only menuù and other accessible methods so your menus etc should be usable using a screen reader and keyboard

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, do I still need a notification or popup stating that only parts of the website is accessible to visually impaired users?

Answer (score 2):

As GACy20 points out, ADA only requires reasonable accommodations. For a graphics editors, the reasonable accommodations for the visually impaired might be somewhat limited, but there are some reasonable steps you should probably take.

I would personally suggest that you not include any kind of popup notification, etc. I would instead, as GACy20 suggests, make the parts of your editing service accessible where possible, without calling out visually impaired users in particular - that would be asking for a complaint, IMHO. It would be far better to be compatible under the [W3C](https://www.w3.org) accessibility standards (eg, screen readable, no keyboard trapping, etc), and not worry about things which are not feasible. There are also [specific standards for authoring tools](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/atag/glance/), which would be good to comply with as much as makes logical sense for each mode of operation of your tool.